# UIImagePicker and AVCaptureSession access camera simultaneously

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller, avcapturesession

I'm wondering if it's possible to have an instance of an `AVCaptureSession` and `UIImagePicker` both accessing the camera simultaneously.

I want to create an app that shows an ambient light meter/indicator as an overlay view of a `UIImagePicker` when the camera is active. I previously implemented this using `UIGetScreenImage()`, but Apple is now disallowing use of this private API in favor of `AVCaptureSession`. In my experimentation, `AVCaptureSession` seems to become suspended when `UIImagePicker` displays the camera view. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: They cannot both access the camera device at the same time. How did UIGetScreenImage() solve this? are you wanting a snapshot with the meter included?

Comment: Hey @John Carter, UIGetScreenImage() simply took a screen shot of the screen, which I could use to analyze the ambient light level of the image being shown from the camera.

Comment: OK, then what you need is AVCaptureSession running (to present your live image) and then if you want to take a photo you use AVCaptureStillImageOutput or (what I'm more familiar with) AVCaptureVideoDataOutput. Your meter should be able to be a realtime view much like I'm doing to convert the realtime view to B&W or other effects in Live Effects Cam

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't be using UIImagePicker for this at all. Instead you should be using an AVCaptureSession.

Here are two tutorials that will help you. The first one shows you how to setup a live camera view and overlay UI elements on top. You can find that [here](http://www.musicalgeometry.com/?p=1273).

The second tutorial shows you how to capture an image from that live camera view. You can find that [here](http://www.musicalgeometry.com/?p=1297).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so that they can not access the both thing simutaneoulsly,